# Dynamic LINQ Performance

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, lambda, expression-trees

I have a routine (written with the generous help of others here) that allows me to take a List objects, and using any number of properties in any order it dynamically builds a TreeView structure with a Count at each node. This dynamic ability is a firm user requirement.

So a source List of:

```
{Prop1 = "A", Prop2 = "I", Prop3 = "X"},  
{Prop1 = "A", Prop2 = "J", Prop3 = "X"},  
{Prop1 = "B", Prop2 = "I", Prop3 = "X"},  
{Prop1 = "B", Prop2 = "I", Prop3 = "Y"},   
{Prop1 = "C", Prop2 = "K", Prop3 = "Z"}
```

Gives the following when the Selection is by Prop1 by Prop3:

```
Total (5)  
- A(2)  
- - X(2)  
- B(2)  
- - X(1)  
- - Y(1)  
- C(1)  
- - Z(1)
```

Functionally this works fine. However, the performance leaves a lot to be desired when the number of distinct values increases. For example - one particular run in a dataset with 5K objects and 1K distinct values in Prop1 will take several seconds.

Here is the routine:

```
    public static class TreeBuilder
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, TreeItem> BuildTree<TSource>(List<TSource> source, List<string> columns)
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, TreeItem>()
                {
                    { "Total",
                      new TreeItem()
                        {
                            Key = "Total",
                            RawKey = "Total",
                            Count = source.Count,
                            Items = GroupBySelector<TSource>(source, columns, 0, "Total")
                        }
                    }
                };
        }

        public static MethodInfo GetGenericMethod(this Type type, string name, Type[] genericTypeArgs, Type[] paramTypes)
        {
            foreach (MethodInfo method in type.GetMethods())
                if (method.Name == name)
                {
                    var pa = method.GetParameters();
                    if (pa.Length == paramTypes.Length)
                    {
                        var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(genericTypeArgs);
                        if (genericMethod.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(paramTypes))
                            return genericMethod;
                    }
                }
            return null;
        }

        private static MethodInfo GetGroupByMethodStatically<TElement, TKey>()
            => typeof(Enumerable).GetGenericMethod("GroupBy", new[] { typeof(TElement), typeof(TKey) }, new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<TElement>), typeof(Func<TElement, TKey>) });

        private static MethodInfo GetEnumerableMethod(string methodName, Type tElement, Type tTKey)
        {
            var tIElement = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(tElement);
            var tFunction = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(tElement, tTKey);
            return typeof(Enumerable).GetGenericMethod(methodName, new[] { tElement, tTKey }, new[] { tIElement, tFunction });
        }

        private static MethodInfo GetEnumerableMethod(string methodName, Type tElement)
        {
            var tIELEMENT = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(tElement);
            return typeof(Enumerable).GetGenericMethod(methodName, new[] { tElement }, new[] { tIELEMENT });
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, TreeItem> GroupBySelector<TElement>(IEnumerable<TElement> source, IList<string> columnNames, int entry = 0, string key = "")
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

            List<string> columnParameters = columnNames[entry].Split('|').ToList();
            string columnName = columnParameters[0];

            if (columnName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(columnName));
            if (columnName.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(columnName));

            int nextEntry = entry + 1;

            var tElement = typeof(TElement);
            var tIElement = typeof(IEnumerable<TElement>);

            var keyParm = Expression.Parameter(tElement);
            var prop = Expression.Property(keyParm, columnName);

            var param = Expression.Parameter(tIElement, "p");
            var groupByMethod = GetEnumerableMethod("GroupBy", tElement, prop.Type);
            var groupByExpr = Expression.Lambda(prop, keyParm);
            var bodyExprCall = Expression.Call(groupByMethod, param, groupByExpr);

            var tSelectInput = typeof(IGrouping<,>).MakeGenericType(prop.Type, tElement);
            var selectParam = Expression.Parameter(tSelectInput, "p");

            var tKey = typeof(TreeItem).GetMember("Key").Single();
            var tRawKey = typeof(TreeItem).GetMember("RawKey").Single();
            var tCount = typeof(TreeItem).GetMember("Count").Single();
            var tParentKey = typeof(TreeItem).GetMember("ParentKey").Single();
            var tItems = typeof(TreeItem).GetMember("Items").Single();

            Expression selectParamKey = Expression.Property(selectParam, "Key");
            Expression selectParamRawKey = selectParamKey;

            if (selectParamKey.Type != typeof(string))
            {
                var toStringMethod = selectParamKey.Type.GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
                selectParamKey = Expression.Call(selectParamKey, toStringMethod);
            }

            if (selectParamRawKey.Type != typeof(string))
            {
                var toStringMethod = selectParamRawKey.Type.GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
                selectParamRawKey = Expression.Call(selectParamRawKey, toStringMethod);
            }

            var countMethod = GetEnumerableMethod("Count", tElement);
            var countMethodExpr = Expression.Call(countMethod, selectParam);

            var concatFullKeyExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string) }),
                                                    Expression.Constant(key),
                                                    Expression.Constant("|"),
                                                    selectParamRawKey);

            var groupBySelectorMethod = GetGenericMethod(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType, "GroupBySelector", new[] { tElement }, new[] { tIElement, typeof(IList<string>), typeof(int), typeof(string) });
            var groupBySelectorMethodExpr = Expression.Call(groupBySelectorMethod, selectParam, Expression.Constant(columnNames), Expression.Constant(nextEntry), concatFullKeyExpr);

            var newMenuItemExpr = Expression.New(typeof(TreeItem));

            var selectBodyExpr = Expression.MemberInit(newMenuItemExpr, new[] {
                                                                                    Expression.Bind(tKey, selectParamKey),
                                                                                    Expression.Bind(tRawKey, selectParamRawKey),
                                                                                    Expression.Bind(tParentKey, Expression.Constant(key) ),
                                                                                    Expression.Bind(tCount, countMethodExpr),
                                                                                    Expression.Bind(tItems, groupBySelectorMethodExpr)
                                                                                 });
            var selectBodyExprLamba = Expression.Lambda(selectBodyExpr, selectParam);

            var selectBodyLastExpr = Expression.MemberInit(newMenuItemExpr, new[] {
                                                                                    Expression.Bind(tKey, selectParamKey),
                                                                                    Expression.Bind(tRawKey, selectParamRawKey),
                                                                                    Expression.Bind(tParentKey, Expression.Constant(key) ),
                                                                                    Expression.Bind(tCount, countMethodExpr)
                                                                                    });
            var selectBodyLastExprLambda = Expression.Lambda(selectBodyLastExpr, selectParam);

            var selectMethod = GetEnumerableMethod("Select", tSelectInput, typeof(TreeItem));
            bodyExprCall = Expression.Call(selectMethod, bodyExprCall, (nextEntry < columnNames.Count) ? selectBodyExprLamba : selectBodyLastExprLambda);

            var selectParamout = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TreeItem), "o");
            Expression selectParamKeyout = Expression.Property(selectParamout, "FullKey");
            var selectParamKeyLambda = Expression.Lambda(selectParamKeyout, selectParamout);

            var lmi = GetEnumerableMethod("ToDictionary", typeof(TreeItem), typeof(string));
            bodyExprCall = Expression.Call(lmi, bodyExprCall, selectParamKeyLambda);

            var returnFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<TElement>, Dictionary<string, TreeItem>>>(bodyExprCall, param).Compile();

            return returnFunc(source);
        }
    }
```

The routine is used to take data from a DB table and convert it into a hierarchical structure for use in a WPF TreeView.

```
 Dictionary<string, TreeItem> treeItems = new Dictionary<string, TreeItem>();
 treeItems = TreeBuilder.BuildTree<IDBRecord>(DBService.GetDBRecordList(), PropertySortList);
```

Can anyone offer any advice on how to improve the performance of this routine? Or suggest any alternative way of achieving the same result in a more performant way?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to change your class into a dynamic class. Instead of using reflection on every step, you'll create everything dynamically, which will be faster. So, try to convert your work to make everything created, and processed at run-time. Also, you can read about creating methods, classes, and properties dynamically to gain more ideas on how you can take advantage of that.

Comment: Could you show how you intend your code to be consumed? The way you describe it and the example output makes me wonder if you really need expression trees here (while still keeping the "dynamic" requirement).

Comment: @ISR5 What makes you think dynamic is faster than reflection, and how would you use dynamic to replace runtime lookup of properties?

Comment: What is `TreeItem`?

Comment: Since `selectParamKey` and `selectParamRawKey` are always the same, can you explain the purpose of `RawKey`?

Comment: @NetMage for the OP case, reflection mainly is not designed to have high-performance by context. While dynamic has better optimization with cache strategy.the OP code mainly works dynamically and depending on reflection which would make things slower, so if converted to dynamic it would improve the overall performance, and if converted into static class that will not use reflection nor dynamic, it'll be much faster.

Comment: I still don't see how runtime Reflection code can be usefully replaced with `dynamic`. `dynamic` is a runtime lookup of a compile time value, not a runtime lookup of a runtime value.

Comment: Where is `TreeItem.FullKey` set in this code?

Comment: TreeItem.FullKey is a property that just returns the concatenation of ParentKey and Key.

Comment: With a "|" between? Have you tried to actually time your code to see where it is being spent? I would not be surprised if a lot of time is spent in the call to `Compile`, which means caching the result might be worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of optimizations are possible. A lot of time is spent in the call to `Compile` and you are calling `Compile` for each key at each level in the tree, which is adding up to a lot of overhead, about 7 seconds on my tests of 5k items. I first changed the code to pull out all static Reflection that had fixed types, so it is only done once per program run. That only made a small difference, since building the `Expression` tree is not the main issue.

I then changed the method to separate building the `Expression` from compiling the `Expression` and calling the resultant lambda. This allowed me to modify the recursive call to the `Expression` builder to instead be an inline `Invoke` of a new lambda for the new level. Then I called compile once on the resulting `Expression` and executed it. The new version no longer takes the `entry` parameter, but it could be put back in.

This reduced the overall time from about 7.6 seconds to 0.14 seconds for around a 50x speedup. A test with all three properties resulted in a 280x speedup.

If it is still possible for repeated calls to the method, adding a cache would be of even more benefit, though a quick test only shows about 14% time savings, and in the hundredths of a second of real time.

```
static MemberInfo tKey = typeof(TreeItem).GetMember("Key").Single();
static MemberInfo tRawKey = typeof(TreeItem).GetMember("RawKey").Single();
static MemberInfo tCount = typeof(TreeItem).GetMember("Count").Single();
static MemberInfo tParentKey = typeof(TreeItem).GetMember("ParentKey").Single();
static MemberInfo tItems = typeof(TreeItem).GetMember("Items").Single();
// Concat(string, string, string)
static MethodInfo Concat3MI = ((Func<string, string, string, string>)String.Concat).Method;
// new TreeItem() { ... }
static NewExpression newMenuItemExpr = Expression.New(typeof(TreeItem));

// Enumerable.ToDictionary<TreeItem>(IEnumerable<TreeItem>, Func<TreeItem,string>)
static MethodInfo ToDictionaryMI = GetEnumerableMethod("ToDictionary", typeof(TreeItem), typeof(string));

static Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TElement>, Dictionary<string, TreeItem>>> BuildGroupBySelector<TElement>(IList<string> columnNames, int entry, Expression key) {
    List<string> columnParameters = columnNames[entry].Split('|').ToList();
    string columnName = columnParameters[0];

    if (columnName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(columnName));
    if (columnName.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(columnName));

    int nextEntry = entry + 1;

    var tElement = typeof(TElement);
    var tIElement = typeof(IEnumerable<TElement>);

    // (TElement kp)
    var keyParm = Expression.Parameter(tElement, "kp");
    // kp.columnName
    var prop = Expression.Property(keyParm, columnName);

    // (IEnumerable<TElement> p)
    var IEParam = Expression.Parameter(tIElement, "p");
    // GroupBy<TElement>(IEnumerable<TElement>, Func<TElement, typeof(kp.columnName)>)
    var groupByMethod = GetEnumerableMethod("GroupBy", tElement, prop.Type);
    // kp => kp.columnName
    var groupByExpr = Expression.Lambda(prop, keyParm);
    // GroupBy(p, kp => kp.columnName)
    var bodyExprCall = Expression.Call(groupByMethod, IEParam, groupByExpr);

    // typeof(IGrouping<typeof(kp.columnName), TElement>)
    var tSelectInput = typeof(IGrouping<,>).MakeGenericType(prop.Type, tElement);
    // (IGrouping<typeof(kp.columnName), TElement> sp)
    var selectParam = Expression.Parameter(tSelectInput, "sp");

    // sp.Key
    Expression selectParamKey = Expression.Property(selectParam, "Key");
    Expression selectParamRawKey = selectParamKey;

    if (selectParamKey.Type != typeof(string)) {
        var toStringMethod = selectParamKey.Type.GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
        // sp.Key.ToString()
        selectParamKey = Expression.Call(selectParamKey, toStringMethod);
        selectParamRawKey = selectParamKey;
    }

    // Count<TElement>()
    var countMethod = GetEnumerableMethod("Count", tElement);
    // sp.Count()
    var countMethodExpr = Expression.Call(countMethod, selectParam);

    LambdaExpression selectBodyExprLamba;
    if (nextEntry < columnNames.Count) {
        // Concat(key, "|", sp.Key.ToString())
        var concatFullKeyExpr = Expression.Call(Concat3MI, key, Expression.Constant("|"), selectParamRawKey);

        // p# => p#.GroupBy().Select().ToDictionary()
        var groupBySelectorLambdaExpr = BuildGroupBySelector<TElement>(columnNames, nextEntry, (Expression)concatFullKeyExpr);
        // Invoke(p# => p#..., sp#)
        var groupBySelectorInvokeExpr = Expression.Invoke(groupBySelectorLambdaExpr, selectParam);

        var selectBodyExpr = Expression.MemberInit(newMenuItemExpr, new[] {
                                                                                Expression.Bind(tKey, selectParamKey),
                                                                                Expression.Bind(tRawKey, selectParamRawKey),
                                                                                Expression.Bind(tParentKey, key ),
                                                                                Expression.Bind(tCount, countMethodExpr),
                                                                                Expression.Bind(tItems, groupBySelectorInvokeExpr)
                                                                             });
        // sp => new TreeItem { Key = sp.Key.ToString(), RawKey = sp.Key.ToString(), ParentKey = key, Count = sp.Count(), Items = Invoke(p# => p#..., sp)) }
        selectBodyExprLamba = Expression.Lambda(selectBodyExpr, selectParam);
    }
    else { // Last Level
        var selectBodyExpr = Expression.MemberInit(newMenuItemExpr, new[] {
                                                                                Expression.Bind(tKey, selectParamKey),
                                                                                Expression.Bind(tRawKey, selectParamRawKey),
                                                                                Expression.Bind(tParentKey, key ),
                                                                                Expression.Bind(tCount, countMethodExpr)
                                                                                });
        // sp => new TreeItem { Key = sp.Key.ToString(), RawKey = sp.Key.ToString(), ParentKey = key, Count = sp.Count() }
        selectBodyExprLamba = Expression.Lambda(selectBodyExpr, selectParam);
    }

    // Enumerable.Select<IGrouping<typeof<kp.columnName>, TElement>>(IEnumerable<IGrouping<>>, Func<IGrouping<>, TreeItem>)
    var selectMethod = GetEnumerableMethod("Select", tSelectInput, typeof(TreeItem));
    // p.GroupBy(kp => kp => kp.columnName).Select(sp => ...)
    bodyExprCall = Expression.Call(selectMethod, bodyExprCall, selectBodyExprLamba);

    // (TreeItem o)
    var selectParamout = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TreeItem), "o");
    // o.FullKey
    Expression selectParamKeyout = Expression.Property(selectParamout, "FullKey");
    // o => o.FullKey
    var selectParamKeyLambda = Expression.Lambda(selectParamKeyout, selectParamout);

    // p.GroupBy(...).Select(...).ToDictionary(o => o.FullKey)
    bodyExprCall = Expression.Call(ToDictionaryMI, bodyExprCall, selectParamKeyLambda);

    // p => p.GroupBy(kp => kp => kp.columnName).Select(sp => ...).ToDictionary(o => o.FullKey)
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<TElement>, Dictionary<string, TreeItem>>>(bodyExprCall, IEParam);
}

public static Dictionary<string, TreeItem> GroupBySelector<TElement>(IEnumerable<TElement> source, IList<string> columnNames, string key = "") {
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    // p => p.GroupBy(kp => kp => kp.columnName).Select(sp => ...).ToDictionary(o => o.FullKey)
    var returnFunc = BuildGroupBySelector<TElement>(columnNames, 0, Expression.Constant(key)).Compile();

    return returnFunc(source);
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution, I'm seeing identical performance improvements in the "real world" application. Great annotation as well - aids my understanding. Thanks.